# How to generate multiple controls with code

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So I'm trying to create the same control (in this case a panel) over and over via my code. I can do this by using this piece of code

```
    int i;
    int PNL_1_Loc = -70;

    private void CreateControls()
    {
        Panel PNL_1 = new Panel();

        i = i + 1;

        PNL_1_Loc= PNL_1_Loc+ 70;
        PNL_1.Location = new Point(0, PNL_1_Loc);
        PNL_1.Name = "PNL_1_" + i.ToString();

        PNL_1.Width = 1052;
        PNL_1.Height = 60;
        PNL_1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(222, 222, 222);
   }
```

Every time I call this function it creates a panel with the name: PNL_1_(panel number). The problem is that I want to acces the PNL_1 variable outside of the function it is created in.

I tried to fix this by placing the PNL_1 variable outside of the function. This doesn't work at all. It can create a panel, but when I press the button for the second time it removes the first panel and creates the second panel. This is a problem because I want to keep the first panel. How do I do this?

Comment: Add each new panel to a [**`List<T>`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a public List outside your Method and add the Panel at the end of it into that list. You will always be able to access all Panel you created.

```
public List<Panel> ExistingSelfMadePanel { get; set;}

private void CreateControls()
{
    //your code
    this.ExistingSelfMadePanel.Add(PNL_1);
}
```

Edit: I don't know how far you are into properties like this, but don't forget to initialize the List!

`this.ExistinSelfMadePanel = new List<Panel>();`

Otherwise you get a null reference exception. Just came into my mind. :)

Edit II:

Here is a "small" [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) from MSDN about the Generic List. There will be shown how to store and access the items you stored in it. Read it carefully and you will be able to access the panels you want. Also, I think you are getting us wrong. To manipulate a existing Panel, load the wanted panel with the help of your List. Something like this:

```
foreach (Panel tmpPanel in Form1.ActiveForm.Controls)
{
  if(tmpPanel.Name == this.ExistingSelfMadePanel.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "PNL_1").Name)
  {
     tmpPanel.ForeColor = Color.Aquamarine;
     break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should use `Add()` rather than `AddRange()` when just adding one item.

Comment: @VisualVincent yeah, true. But somehow won't debug if I do so... strange. EDIT: Sry you are right :)

Comment: I get an error when I try this: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.Panel' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.Panel>' toDoPlanner E:\Projects\Apps\toDoPlanner\toDoPlanner\Form1.cs 59 Active

Comment: @unknown : Use `Add()` instead of `AddRange()`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, I did that but I still cannot acces my PNL_1 outside the method

Comment: @unknown how exactly do you try to access your panel...?

Comment: If it is in a list can't you do something like var myPanel = PanelList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "<Name of panel you want to reference>")? (PanelList is the variable name of the list).

Comment: Could somebody type some code using the given code for me? It's the first time I've heard about lists in C#.